# how to skip browser cache in each release of a web page

Tags: caching, web, browser-cache

I want to make browsers not to remember or read cache items for each release of my web application. But for between releases, it can use its cache. I do not want to make browsers download content resources each time.

Is there any signature or mark that indicates for browsers that this is a release and do not use cache items?

thx

Ali

Answer (score 1):

If you have a semi-regular release cycle, simply set 'Expires' header for all of your content to expire regularly and check for new content (e.g. weekly, monthly).